# Setting a date + 8 days inside a value in a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new column in pandas in which I get a comment that says: Opened today() need update in today + 8 days. This is what I've got, but have not been able to fix this error.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

Today = datetime.date.today() 

def add_days_to_date(date, days):
    subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) + timedelta(days=days)
    subtracted_date = subtracted_date.strftime("%m-%d")

    return(subtracted_date)

RepliedSent_date = ("Opened", Today, "need update", add_days_to_date(Today, 8))

df.loc[(df['col1'] != ' ') & (df['col2'] != ' '), "Replied/sent date"] = RepliedSent_date
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you can't assing `= RepliedSent_date` to get result. You have to use `.apply()` to execute function on every value - and it may need `lambda` because your function gets two values `.apply(lambda value:RepliedSent_date(value, 8))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assing `= RepliedSent_date` to get result.

You have to create function `RepliedSent_date(date)`

```
def RepliedSent_date(date):
    return f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 8)}"
```

or

```
RepliedSent_date = lambda date: f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 8)}"
```

and use `.apply()` to execute this function on every row.

```
mask = ...
df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].apply(RepliedSent_date)
```

---

Minimal working code with example data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# --- functions ---

def add_days_to_date(date, days):
    subtracted_date = pd.to_datetime(date) + timedelta(days=days)
    subtracted_date = subtracted_date.strftime("%m-%d")
    return subtracted_date

def replied_sent_date(date):
    return f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 8)}"

#replied_sent_date = lambda date: f"Opened {date} need update {add_days_to_date(date, 8)}"

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', ' '],
    'col2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '],
    'Replied/sent date': ['2022.10.24', '2022.10.23', '2022.10.25', '2000.01.01'],
})

mask = (df['col1'] != ' ') & (df['col2'] != ' ')
df.loc[mask, "Replied/sent date"] = df.loc[mask, "Replied/sent date"].apply(replied_sent_date)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2                    Replied/sent date
0    A    X  Opened 2022.10.24 need update 11-01
1    B    Y  Opened 2022.10.23 need update 10-31
2    C    Z  Opened 2022.10.25 need update 11-02
3                                     2000.01.01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Replied/sent date']=(df.loc[(df['col1'] != ' ') & (df['col2'] != ' ')]['date']
                         .apply(lambda x: "Opened " + str(x.strftime('%F') ) + " , need update, " + str((x+ pd.offsets.Day(8)).strftime('%F')))
)
df
```

```
col1    col2    date    Replied/sent date
0           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
1           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
2           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
3           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
4           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
5           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
6           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
7           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
8           2021-01-04  Opened 2021-01-04 , need update, 2021-01-12
```